# How to tar files from multiple paths without including path names?

Tags: tar

At the end of an automated job, I want to tar up some logfiles and deposit them somewhere in case they need to be analyzed. The log files are at multiple different locations on the host, and some of them can be quite large.

Suppose the following files exist and I want all of them:

```
/app/app_stderr.log
/app/app_stdout.log
/var/log/service/service.log
/var/lib/service/service_backend.log
/var/log/messages.log
```

However I don't want any paths in the tarfile. I just want the five files as-is:

```
app_stderr.log
app_stdout.log
service.log
service_backend.log
messages.log
```

I also want the tar archive gzip compressed. Ideally I'd like to do this in the most efficient way possible - i.e. not having to make copies of the logfiles or store an uncompressed tarfile temporarily before gzipping it.

The `-C` option that is often given as a solution to similar questions is not applicable to me since I want to tar files from *multiple* directories in different parts of the filesystem while still stripping off the path names.

If I just run:

```
tar -czf /drop/run_logs.tar.gz /app/app_*.log /var/log/service/*.log /var/lib/service/*.log /var/log/messages.log
```

then I'm going to get a tarfile with the paths included.

Possible to accomplish stripping the paths?

Comment: `-C` can be used multiple times, but it’s hard to combine with wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

The tar `--transform` option allow you to modify the filename before writing to the tar file. This option will run the filenames through a `sed` expression before they get written to the tar file. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/transform.html) for the full details.

Here is a quick example.

First create a few files to add to a tar file

```
$ mkdir test-tar
$ cd test-tar

$ mkdir -p alpha/beta/gamma

$ touch alpha/one.log
$ touch alpha/beta/two.log
$ touch alpha/beta/gamma/three.log
```

use a standard `tar` to reproduce the tar file with the full relative paths.

```
$ tar cf test.tar alpha/*.log alpha/beta/*.log alpha/beta/gamma/*.log
$ tar tf test.tar
alpha/one.log
alpha/beta/two.log
alpha/beta/gamma/three.log
```

Now redo the command but using the `--transform` option. In the example I'm using the sed expression `s#.*/##` to delete all leading characters in the filename up to the rightmost `/`.

```
$ tar cf test-transform.tar alpha/*.log alpha/beta/*.log alpha/beta/gamma/*.log --transform='s#.*/##'
```

now see what was written to the tar file

```
$ tar tf test-transform.tar 
one.log
two.log
three.log
```

no leading paths present.